# How to set log_level for the assets:precompile task?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rake, rake-task

There is a method `Rake::SprocketsTask#log_level=` (defined by `sprockets-3.7.1/lib/rake/sprocketstask.rb`) but how to call it?

[Rafael França says](https://github.com/rails/sprockets-rails/issues/314#issuecomment-191344546):

> To change the logger you can define your own precompile tasks and
>   setting logger=
>
> ```
> Rake::SprocketsTask.new do |t|   
>   t.logger = Logger.new("log/assets.log") 
> end
> ```

I tried that (with `log_level`) and it returns a `SprocketsTask` instance, but how do I replace the `assets:precompile` task?

I want to set the `log_level` of the `assets:precompile` task to something quieter, like `:warn`.

Comment: You can set  `config.assets.quiet = true`, in your environments/development.rb

Answer (score 0):

some feedback, `logger` is an `attribute` of the class `SprocketsTask`.

```
require 'logger'

module Rake
    # Simple Sprockets compilation Rake task macro.
    #
    #   Rake::SprocketsTask.new do |t|
    #     t.environment = Sprockets::Environment.new
    #     t.output      = "./public/assets"
    #     t.assets      = %w( application.js application.css )
    #   end
    #
    class SprocketsTask < Rake::TaskLib 
        # Logger to use during rake tasks. Defaults to using stderr.
        #
        #   t.logger = Logger.new($stdout)
        #
        attr_accessor :logger
```

I did not find the info in the [api](http://api.rubyonrails.org/), there is some good explanation in the [Rails Guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/debugging_rails_applications.html#the-logger) about the [Log4r](https://github.com/colbygk/log4r) logger used by rails.

This is the explanation of the code you included

> Rails makes use of the ActiveSupport::Logger class to write log information. Other loggers, such as Log4r, may also be substituted.
>
> You can specify an alternative logger in config/application.rb or any other environment file, for example:

```
config.logger = Logger.new(STDOUT)
config.logger = Log4r::Logger.new("Application Log")
```

That command creates a log file by default under Rails.root/log/

The info you need are about [`log levels`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/debugging_rails_applications.html#log-levels)

> When something is logged, it's printed into the corresponding log if the log level of the message is equal to or higher than the configured log level. If you want to know the current log level, you can call the `Rails.logger.level` method.
>
> The available log levels are: `:debug`, `:info`, `:warn`, `:error`, `:fatal`, and `:unknown`, corresponding to the log level numbers from 0 up to 5, respectively. To change the default log level, use

```
config.log_level = :warn # In any environment initializer, or
Rails.logger.level = 0 # at any time
```

This is the `Log4r::Logger.rb` class.
It has `attr_reader` for `:level`, which is set with the `def initizialize`.

```
module Log4r
  
  # See log4r/logger.rb
  class Logger
    attr_reader :name, :fullname, :path, :level, :parent
    attr_reader :additive, :trace, :outputters

    # Logger requires a name. The last 3 parameters are:
    #
    # level::     Do I have a level? (Otherwise, I'll inherit my parent's)
    # additive::  Am I additive?
    # trace::     Do I record the execution trace? (slows things a wee bit) 

    def initialize(_fullname, _level=nil, _additive=true, _trace=false)
      # validation
      raise ArgumentError, "Logger must have a name", caller if _fullname.nil?
      Log4rTools.validate_level(_level) unless _level.nil?
      validate_name(_fullname)
      
      # create the logger
      @fullname = _fullname
      @outputters = []
      @additive = _additive
      deal_with_inheritance(_level)
      LoggerFactory.define_methods(self)
      self.trace = _trace
      Repository[@fullname] = self
    end
```

You can set the level by doing:

```
Log4r::Logger.new('Assets Log', :warn)
```

So I believe `t.logger.level = 2` should set the `level` to `:warn`

```
Rake::SprocketsTask.new do |t|   
  t.logger = Logger.new("log/assets.log") 
  t.logger.level = 2
end
```

> `:debug`, `:info`, `:warn`, `:error`, `:fatal`, and `:unknown`, corresponding to the log level numbers from 0 up to 5, respectively.

Also this works because, `Log4r::Logger` has a method `def level=(_level)` to re-set the `level` attribute.

```
# Set the logger level dynamically. Does not affect children.
def level=(_level)
  Log4rTools.validate_level(_level)
  @level = _level
  LoggerFactory.define_methods(self)
  Logger.log_internal {"Logger '#{@fullname}' set to #{LNAMES[@level]}"}
  @level
end
```

Comment: Thanks for the detailed response ❤️, but (as I said) I already tried `Rake::SprocketsTask.new` and it does not *replace* the existing task. IOW, just calling that constructor appears to have no effect on `rake assets:precompile`.